# Comparison operator performance (>, >=, <, <=)

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, comparison, operators

If you were to compare two integers, would the operator have an impact on the time required to perform the comparison? For example, given:

```cpp
if (x < 60)
```

and

```cpp
if (x <= 59)
```

Which would provide the best performance, or would the performance difference be negligible? Are the performance results language-dependent?

I often find myself mixing the use of these operators within my code. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, there indeed is a performance difference (at least in JavaScript): on my machine `x < 60` takes 1103,1 picoseconds to execute, and `x <= 59` takes 1103,2 picoseconds to execute, making it a tenth of a picosecond slower. Mind blown `:)` [See for yourself](http://jsperf.com/less-than-vs-greater-than-or-equal)

Comment: @Šime Vidas: That's pretty cool. Those results are definitely browser-dependent.

Comment: Yes, in IE9 `<=` is in fact 32% slower (!!) (which is 2.7 nanoseconds on my machine).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is < faster than <=?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135518/is-faster-than)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even if there was noticeable difference, I think compilers are smart enough to care for such things. So my advice is to use what makes the code easier to understand, and leave micro-optimizations to the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

In the specific example you gave where one side is constant, I'd expect an optimizer to transform one to the other if it was significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

The differences are negligible.  Theoretically they could be language dependent.

As another answer mentioned, they are also theoretically platform dependent.

See: [Is the inequality operator faster than the equality operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029992/is-the-inequality-operator-faster-than-the-equality-operator)

Answer (score 0):

There is almost certainly no difference in performance.  For CISC processors, you'll typically have all manner of branch instructions that cope with all the difference < <= > >= etc.  On RISC there may be a very small performance difference although I'd seriously doubt it!