# Speed of Comparison operators

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, operator-keyword

In languages such as... well anything, both operators for < and <= (and their opposites) exist.  Which would be faster, and how are they interpreted?

> if (x <= y) { blah; }

or

> if (x < y + 1) { blah; }

Comment: As with most other optimization/performance questions, it depends on too many factors (compiler, exact code it's used in, etc.). But if you're worrying about optimization at this level, you're wasting time you could probably use 1000+ times in other parts of your code.

Comment: @Ken White, +1 because you're right in general, and it's important to keep that in mind. However, I think it's good practice to adopt simple guidelines (as long as they don't hurt readability) that will tend to make code faster on average. You see this all the time in C/C++ with the preference for passing objects by reference instead of by value. No single passing really hurts performance that much, but they add up. (This case is obviously far less important.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparison operator performance (>, >=, <, <=)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861222/comparison-operator-performance)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming no compiler optimizations (big assumption), the first will be faster, as <= is implemented by a single `jle` instruction, where as the latter requires an addition followed by a `jl` instruction.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Jump_if_Less

Comment: With modern pipelined processors, you can't use instruction counts to predict performance.

Comment: Voight: absolutely, I should've added that to my initial disclaimer about the compiler. However, I'd argue that you can predict the first will be no _slower_ than the second in all cases I can think of, and it might occasionally be faster (although only on machines probably 10 years old or older, and only marginally so then).

Comment: Is `jl` faster than `jle`? Is there a speed difference between `x <= y + 1` and `x < y + 2`?

Comment: @AaronFranke — it's incredibly unlikely there would ever be a speed difference there. I cannot imagine either a machine architecture or compiler where there would be a difference in speed.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't worry about this at all as far as performance goes.  Using C as an example, on a simple test I ran with GCC 4.5.1 targeting x86 (with `-O2`), the `(x <=y )` operation compiled to:

```
    // if (x <= y) {
    //     printf( "x <= y\n");
    // }
    //
    // `x` is [esp+28]
    // `y` is [esp+24]

    mov eax, DWORD PTR [esp+24]     // load `y` into eax 
    cmp DWORD PTR [esp+28], eax     // compare with `x`
    jle L5                          // if x < y, jump to the `true` block
L2:

    // ...

    ret

L5: // this prints "x <= y\n"
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:LC1
    call    _puts
    jmp L2      // jumps back to the code after the ` if statement
```

and the `(x < y + 1)` operation compiled to:

```
    // if (x < y +1) {
    //     printf( "x < y+1\n");
    // }
    //
    // `x` is [esp+28]
    // `y` is [esp+24]

    mov eax, DWORD PTR [esp+28]     // load x into eax
    cmp DWORD PTR [esp+24], eax     // compare with y
    jl  L3                          //  jump past the true block if (y < x)
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:LC2
    call    _puts
L3:
```

So you might have a difference of a jump around a jump or so, but you should really only be concerned about this kind of thing for the odd time where it really is a hot spot.  Of course there may be differences between languages and what exactly happens might depend on the type of objects that are being compared. But I'd still not worry about this at all as far as performance is concerned (until it became a demonstrated performance issue - which I'll be surprised if it ever does for more than once or twice in my lifetime).

So, I think the only two reasons to worry about which test to use are:

- correctness - of course, *this trumps any other consideration*
- style/readabilty

While you might not think there's much to the style/readability consideration, I do worry about this a little. In my C and C++ code today, I'd favor using the `<` operator over `<=` because I think loops tend to terminate 'better' using a `<` than a `<=` test. So, for example:

- iterating over an array by index, you should typically use an `index < number_of_elements` test
- iterating over an array using pointers to elements should use a `ptr < (array + number_of_elements)` test

Actually even in C, I now tend to use a `ptr != (array + number_of_elements)` since I've gotten used to STL iterators where the `<` relation won work.

In fact, if I see a `<=` test in a `for` loop condition, I take a close look - often there's a bug lurking. I consider it an anti-pattern.

Noe I'll grant that a lot of this may not hold for other languages, but I be surprised if when I'm using another language that there's ever a performance issues I'll have to worry about because I chose to use `<` over `<=`.

Answer (score 2):

What data-type?

If `y` is `INT_MAX`, then the first expression is `true` no matter what `x` is (assuming `x` is the same or smaller type), while the second expression is always `false`.

If the answer doesn't need to be right, you can get it even faster.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that both those arguments are different? In case x and y are floating point numbers - they may not give the same result. That is the reason both comparison operators exists.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this as vague as you have has caused this to be an unanswerable question.  Performance cannot be evaluated unless you have software and hardware to measure - what language?  what language implementation?  what target CPU architecture?  etc.

That being said, both `<=` and `<` are often identical performance-wise, because they are logically equivalent to `>` and `>=`, just with swapped destinations for the underlying goto's (branch instructions), or swapped logic for the underlying "true/false" evaluation.

If you're programming in C or C++, the compiler may be able to figure out what you're doing, and swap in the faster alternative, anyway.

Write code that is understandable, maintainable, correct, and performant, in that order.  For performance, find tools to measure the performance of your whole program, and spend your time wisely.  Optimize bottlenecks only until your program is fast enough.  Spend the time you save by making better code, or making more cool features :)

Answer (score 0):

Prefer the first one.

In some languages with dynamic types the running environment has to figure out what the type of y is and execute the appropriate + operator.