# Is there a difference between >= and just >?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

Given:

```
var x = 2;

if (x >= 1)
    // do stuff

if (x > 0)
    // do stuff
```

Both conditions will be true, but is there a difference in terms of performance? Should one be used over the other in terms of standardization?

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UGy5z/)

Comment: I guess the firs one compares two thing therefore will be slower. But I don't think this can affect performance.

Comment: I think the answer might be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861222/comparison-operator-performance

Comment: Use whichever one makes the code more readable. You will see a negligible performance difference across all browsers and the only way you would notice it is if you are looping a `for()` loop a couple million times because those picoseconds will really add up!

Comment: Use http://jsperf.com/ and find out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer `x > 0`, because it is easier to read.

In terms of performance I'm almost confident that they're equal.
That being said, I think the most important thing is to consistently use either style.

Answer (score -1):

The >= means if the first statement is larger of equal to.
The > means if the first state ment is larger.

for example:

```
x=4;

if( x >= 4 ){
  echo "This is TRUE since x is bigger OR equal to 4";
}
if( x > 4 ){
  echo "This is FALSE since x isn't bigger than 4, it is 4.";
}

if( x <= 4){
  echo "This is TRUE since x is smaller or equal to 4.";
}

if( x < 4){
  echo "This is FALSE since x isn't smaller than 4.";
}
```