# I don't understand the difference

Tags: java, performance, processing-efficiency

I was reviewing some Java code with this line

```
if ( list.size() == 1 || list.size() <= 4) {...}
```

I commented that I do not see how that is any different from just doing

```
if (list.size() <= 4) {...}
```

he said it matters and needs to be the first.  I don't understand.  Perhaps if it were something like

```
if (list.size() == 1 || list.size() <= someVeryCostlyFunction() ) {...}
```

and the size was expected to be 1 most of the time you might use both, if someVeryCostlyFunction() always returns some positive number >= 1.  Otherwise I can't see the difference.  We are supposed to check for efficiency.

Comment: `"it matters and needs to be the first"` - This doesn't sound like a compelling answer to the question.  I wouldn't put much stock in the actions of people who can't explain why they did those actions.

Comment: then you have to compute `list.size()` once for starters ...

Comment: By "needs to be the first" I meant the first example with the two conditions, and not the second with just the one condition

Comment: @Tony Looks to me that the developer just doesn't want to admit that a silly mistake was made. But I am now curious to see how the code is justified.

Comment: @Tony yeah, it would be interesting to know what was the outcome

Comment: I think you guys are right that he did not want to admit to a mistake.  I have done similar stuff in C like instead of declaring int x and passing &x to a function, I declared int *x and passed x, which is of course stupid if it was never initialized.  But I digress.... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The code [smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) with those two conditions:

```
if (list.size() == 1 || list.size() <= 4)
```

Perhaps the author have that in mind:

> if there is some number of elements in the list that is 4 or less.

More over the current code allows to satisfy the condition even if the list has zero elements - which is most likely wrong.

Another problem with this condition is use of [magic number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882/4454454) 4? 
What is so important about it and why it is not `5`?
It should be self documented and distinguished from other 4's that could appear in the code:

```
int MAX_HANDLED = 4;
if ( list.size() > 0 && list.size() <= MAX_HANDLED )
:
:
int ALL_TIRES = 4;
if (car.getTires() < ALL_TIRES) {
  car.stop();
}
```

As for the performance, I do not see any significant reason why existing condition should be any faster then yours proposed one (even the second would be faster when `list.size > 1`). See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5861222/4454454) of similar concern.

Comment: I see now he wanted to be alerted if the size was > 4 but you still don't need the == 1.  And you do need a >0 although I guess you will get an assertion error is size == 0:  WebElement ele = lists.get(0).  Will give an assertion (or size = 0 ind = 0 or something)

Comment: If there is already an assertion for empty list then you do not need first check. So the check you proposed should be sufficient.