# How java comparison operator works

Tags: java, android

I think

```
if( newItem.ReceiptNo != 0 && newItem.ReceiptYear != 0 && newItem.SR != 0)
```

and

```
if( ! ( newItem.ReceiptNo == 0 && newItem.ReceiptYear == 0 && newItem.SR == 0))
```

Should be same. But I am not getting same result on android

Comment: both are not same. its deffer in operator `&&` and `||` .

Comment: Actually, Its simple Digital Logic , **AND** and **NOR** gate logic.

Comment: One word: short-circuit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic doesn't work that way.

```
if( newItem.ReceiptNo != 0 && newItem.ReceiptYear != 0 && newItem.SR != 0)
```

is the same as

```
if( ! ( newItem.ReceiptNo == 0 || newItem.ReceiptYear == 0 || newItem.SR == 0))
```

Notice the `||` instead of `&&`.

See also: [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score 0):

You would be wrong, carry out the negation on your second if

```
if (newItem.ReceiptNo != 0 || newItem.ReceiptYear != 0 || newItem.SR != 0)
```

Remember the negation of `and` is `or`.

Answer (score 0):

**Statement 1**

```
if(newItem.ReceiptNo != 0 && newItem.ReceiptYear != 0 && newItem.SR != 0)
```

This means that all 3 should not be zero

**Statement 2**

```
if( !(newItem.ReceiptNo == 0 && newItem.ReceiptYear == 0 && newItem.SR == 0))
```

first 
`newItem.ReceiptNo == 0 && newItem.ReceiptYear == 0 && newItem.SR == 0` means all 3 should be zero and not of this means any of the 3 should not be zero

to this to be same change this with

```
if( !(newItem.ReceiptNo == 0 || newItem.ReceiptYear == 0 || newItem.SR == 0))
```

**for eg**

```
a != b is equal to !(a=b)
(a != b && a != c) is equal to !(a=b || a=c)
(a != b || a != c) is equal to !(a=b && a=c)
```

whenever !operator comes out and applied on result of some operations then it will revert all opertion like && will convert into || and || will convert into &&.

Answer (score 0):

Even if there was noticeable difference, I think compilers are smart enough to care for such things. So my advice is to use what makes the code easier to understand, and leave micro-optimizations to the compiler.

See : [Is the inequality operator faster than the equality operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029992/is-the-inequality-operator-faster-than-the-equality-operator)